# How to deploy and verify(public source code) ethereum smart contract programmatically?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I want to deploy an ethereum smart contract and verify(reveal) its source code. Can I do it programmatically?

Usually I deploy a smart contract and verify it on etherscan.io. After the verification the source code is revealed. The task is that I need to deploy a lot of smart contracts but I can not verify them manually. Is there a way or API to upload the solidity code to reveal smart contract code to the public?

Though I guess the answer is "no" but still want to hear any ideas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't a satisfying answer at the moment, but https://github.com/ethpm/ethpm-spec is an attempt to solve this, with reproducible contract package compilations. https://github.com/ethpm/py-ethpm is one in-progress implementation of the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, at the time of writing this, it seems like there's no public endpoint to do this. There's no mention of such contract verification endpoint in Etherscan documentation here https://etherscan.io/apis or here https://hexdocs.pm/etherscan/

Someone was asking the same thing on their [subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/etherscan/comments/7irp6u/request_api_endpoint_for_verifying_contracts/) just about a month ago, without much success

Etherscan is using `Are you a robot?` checkbox CAPTCHA upon verification. That one would be pretty hard to trick, not really worth trying. What you could do instead however is a **partial automation of contract verification using Selenium**.

Lets say you want to verify 20 contracts with minimal effort. It should be possible to write a script which would open up 20 tabs in browser, in each it would go to Etherscan, enter appropriate contract details for one of the contracts, but then let a human to handle the page with `Are you a robot?` captcha.

Answer (score 1):

Etherscan has an HTTP API, with which contracts can be verified programmatically

https://docs.etherscan.io/tutorials/verifying-contracts-programmatically

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).